# monotouch play music when device is locked

Tags: audio, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to make my monotouch app continue playing when the device is locked, I found this snippet in ObjC, was wondering if mt already has bindings for it or not.

```
AudioSessionInitialize (NULL,NULL,interruptionListenerCallback,self);
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
AudioSession.Initialize ();
AudioSession.Interrupted += delegate {
  Console.WriteLine ("Interrupted handler");
};
AudioSession.Category = AudioSessionCategory.MediaPlayback;
```

Comment: Hi @Geoff Norton. Is there any special way I should do this or implement it and where do I implement it? The appDelegate? ViewDidLoad? Do I have to hook the AudioSession to my MediaPlayer in any way in the code? I also take it there are references that have to be added like AudioToolbox? Sorry I'm a bit of a newby with monotouch and I am struggling with this particular problem. Thanks J